# Invisible Recaptchav3: How to get Error Callback in React Native

Tags: android, ios, reactjs, react-native, recaptcha

I'm struggling with Invisible Recaptcha v3 by Google. I've implemented it and it works fine, but I haven't been able to find a way in case recaptcha fails due to network issue etc...

I've implemented it as follows:

```
import React from "react";
import { StyleSheet, View } from "react-native";
import { WebView } from "react-native-webview";
import { platform } from "./constants";

type IProps = {
  captchaDomain: string;
  onReceiveToken: (captchaToken: string, callback?: Function) => void;
  siteKey: string;
};

const patchPostMessageJsCode = `(${String(function() {
  const originalPostMessage = window.postMessage;
  const patchedPostMessage = (
    message: any,
    targetOrigin: any,
    transfer: any
  ) => {
    originalPostMessage(message, targetOrigin, transfer);
  };
  patchedPostMessage.toString = () =>
    String(Object.hasOwnProperty).replace("hasOwnProperty", "postMessage");
  window.postMessage = patchedPostMessage;
})})();`;

const getExecutionFunction = (siteKey: string) => {
  return `window.grecaptcha.execute('${siteKey}', { action: 'login' }).then(
    function(args) {
      window.ReactNativeWebView.postMessage(args);
    }
  )`;
};

const getInvisibleRecaptchaContent = (siteKey: string) => {
  return `<!DOCTYPE html><html><head>
    <script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js?render=${siteKey}" onerror="onErrorCallback()"></script>
    <script>window.grecaptcha.ready(function() { ${getExecutionFunction(
      siteKey
    )} });</script>
    </head></html>`;
};

class ReCaptchaComponent extends React.Component<IProps> {
  private _webViewRef = React.createRef<WebView>();

  private _callbackFunction?: Function;

  public refreshToken(onReceiveCallback?: Function) {
    const { siteKey } = this.props;
    this._callbackFunction = onReceiveCallback;
    if (platform.isIOS && this._webViewRef.current) {
      this._webViewRef.current.injectJavaScript(getExecutionFunction(siteKey));
    } else if (platform.isAndroid && this._webViewRef.current) {
      this._webViewRef.current.reload();
    }
  }

  render() {
    const { captchaDomain, onReceiveToken, siteKey } = this.props;
    return (
      <View style={styles.webViewContainer}>
        <WebView
          ref={this._webViewRef}
          style={styles.webView}
          javaScriptEnabled
          originWhitelist={["*"]}
          automaticallyAdjustContentInsets={false}
          mixedContentMode="always"
          injectedJavaScript={patchPostMessageJsCode}
          source={{
            html: getInvisibleRecaptchaContent(siteKey),
            baseUrl: captchaDomain,
          }}
          onMessage={(e: any) => {
            console.log(`${JSON.stringify(e.nativeEvent.data)}`);
            // if (onReceiveToken) {
            //   onReceiveToken(e.nativeEvent.data, this._callbackFunction);
            // }
          }}
        />
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  webViewContainer: { height: 50, overflow: "hidden", opacity: 0 },
  webView: { width: 50, height: 50, overflow: "hidden", opacity: 0.9 },
});

export default ReCaptchaComponent;
```

I haven't been able to get an error callback in case something goes wrong. I tried .catch but it didn't work:

```
const getExecutionFunction = (siteKey: string) => {
  return `window.grecaptcha.execute('${siteKey}', { action: 'login' }).then(
    function(args) {
      window.ReactNativeWebView.postMessage(args);
    }
  ).catch(function(args) {
      window.ReactNativeWebView.postMessage(args);
    })`;
};
```

Am I missing something here ?